# Spring MVC: 404 The requested resource is not available

Tags: spring-mvc

I am new in Spring MVC. Test "helloworld" example in localhost:8080 it is fine.
But I create my own project then come with 404 The requested resource is not available.

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.tachubsystems.TERMS.controller"></context:component-scan>
    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
    <bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
 </beans>
```

LoginController.java

```
package com.tachubsystems.TERMS.controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String test()
    {
     return "login";
    }
}
```

file directory: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1cxH.png 
404 error page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIcjW.png

Comment: try navigating to {rootcontext}/login, ex: localhost:8080/login or localhost:8080/TERMS/login

Comment: still same problem, i also get a warning about dispatcher.
org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TERMS/login] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'

Comment: try changing @RequestMapping("/login") to @RequestMapping("/TERMS/login")

Comment: get same warning. even tried localhost:8080 also same.

Comment: What is the name of your project in eclipse? Is it actually 'TERMS'?

Comment: ya, project name is  "TERMS"

Comment: how are you deploying the application?

Comment: Maven build (goals:package)-> run on server, set targeted runtime as apache tomcat 7. will update project when meet error/warning

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to configure the `servlet` tag with below codes in `web.xml`.

<servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```